# Mongorito `before save` hook doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongorito

I'm following the examples to abort `save` but doesn't work in node v8.0.0.

I also test with `--harmony` parameter but nothing.

I follow next example for my test: [Example](http://mongorito.com/guides/middleware/)

And my example code:

```
const {Database, Model} = require('mongorito');

void async function(){
  const db = new Database('localhost:27017/blog');
  await db.connect();

  class Post extends Model {
    constructor(fields){
      fields.hello = 'world';
      super(fields);
    }

    configure () {
        this.before('save', 'validate');
    }

    * validate (next) {
        console.log('in hook');

        let isValid = true;

        if (isValid) {
            throw new Error('Post title is missing');
        }

        yield next;
    }
  }
  db.register(Post);

  const post = new Post({
    title: 'Steve Angello rocks',
    author: {
      name: 'Emma'
    }
  });

  await post.save();

  post.set('author.name', 'Rick');
  await post.save();
}();
```

The `post` is saved w/o errors.

Comment: It looks like the website doesn't match the README [here](https://github.com/vadimdemedes/mongorito), so I think the documentation that you're using is outdated.